# autoscale the plot `plotly`

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I need to produce a plot of errors between the true and predicted arrays. I've managed to do it with `plotly`, as shown in `Code 1`, but the produced plot has too much space on the top. If I press the `autoscale` button in the plot - it fixes it.

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

N = 40
y1 = np.random.randint(0, 2, N)
y2 = np.random.randint(0, 2, N)
err = np.where(y1 != y2)[0]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=err, 
        y=np.zeros_like(err), 
        name='Prediction Errors', 
        mode='markers', 
        marker_symbol='x', 
        marker_color='red',
        showlegend=True
    )
)
fig.update_layout(title_text = 'Errors in activity prediction', height=10)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text = 'User index', range=[-0.3, N])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-0.01, 0.1], visible=False)
```

**Produced image:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

**My question:**

Can it be done automatically (i.e.without me needing to press the `autoscale` button each time)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
fig['layout']['yaxis'].update(autorange = True)
```