# update specific subplot axes in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

**Setup:**

- I'm tring to plot a subplots with `plotly` library, but can't figure out how to reference a specific subplots' axis to change its' name (or other properties).
- In `Code 1` I show a simple example where I add two plots one on thop of the other with `plotly.subplots.make_subplots`.

**Code 1**

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from math import exp

fig = make_subplots(2, 1)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-0.1 * x + 5)), x)))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=f'\N{Greek Small Letter Sigma}(x)',
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)

x = np.where(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)==1)[0]
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=np.zeros_like(x),
        name=f'Plot 2',
        mode='markers', 
        marker=dict(
                symbol='circle-open',
                color='green',
                size=5
            ),
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)
fig.show()
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried using the `fig.update_xaxes()` after each trace addition, but it messes the plots and does not produce the desired output, as shown in `Code 2`.

**Code 2:**

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from math import exp

fig = make_subplots(2, 1)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-0.1 * x + 5)), x)))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=f'\N{Greek Small Letter Sigma}(x)',
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='x')
x = np.where(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)==1)[0]
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=np.zeros_like(x),
        name=f'Plot 2',
        mode='markers', 
        marker=dict(
                symbol='circle-open',
                color='green',
                size=5
            ),
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='active users')
fig.show()
```

which results in (note the `active users` being printed on the top):

[image]

**My Questions:**

1. How can I assign the top plot x axis the label `x`, and `active users` label to the x axis of the bottom plot?
2. And in general - how can I access the properties of an individual subplot?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63579310/4596078) I as able to solve it, by referencing the `xaxis` for plot on the position `row=1`, `col=1` and the `xaxis1` for the plot on the `row=2`, `col=1` position. The full solution is in `Code 1`.

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from math import exp

fig = make_subplots(2, 1)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-0.1 * x + 5)), x)))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=f'\N{Greek Small Letter Sigma}(x)',
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
fig['layout']['xaxis'].update(title_text='x')

x = np.where(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)==1)[0]
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=np.zeros_like(x),
        name=f'Plot 2',
        mode='markers', 
        marker=dict(
                symbol='circle-open',
                color='green',
                size=5
            ),
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1
)
fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(title_text='active users')

fig.show()
```

Cheers.

Comment: `fig.layout` is slightly safer than `fig['layout']`.

Comment: instead of 2 `fig['layout']['xaxis#'].update(title_text='asdf')`, this may look better `fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title_text='x'), xaxis2=dict(title_text='active users'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.select_xaxes()` to address an axis by its `col` and `row` in the grid if you are not sure what its `xaxis#` ID is.

This may help you if you traverse the grid in a non-sequential way or have multiple axes or different types (e.g. you mix `pie` and `scatter` types) on some subplots.

I have rendered all the necessary traces individually and then populate an empty facet 5×5 grid like this:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=5, cols=5)
for i, subplot in enumerate(rendered_subplots):
    fig.add_trace(subplot.data[0], row = 1 + i//5, col = 1 + i%5)
    next(fig.select_xaxes(row=1 + i//5, col= 1 + i%5)).update(title="Speed",
                                               tickmode = 'array',
                                               tickvals = [1,2,3,4],
                                               ticktext = ['Very slow', 'Slow', 'Fast', 'Very fast'])
```

If you have pre-formatted the axes in each subplot that you pluck from `rendered_subplots`, you can take it further and graft the axes properties this way:

```
    rendered_xaxis = next(subplot.select_xaxes())
    this_xaxis = next(fig.select_xaxes(row = 1 + i//5, col = 1 + i%5))
    this_xaxis.update({x:rendered_xaxis[x] for x in
                       ["tickmode", "ticktext", "tickvals", "title"]})
```